# Destroy SDL_Window without destroying native window handle?

Tags: video, rendering, sdl-2

I am implementing a video player API sw which plays video for given Rtsp adress. 
Softwares which use API pass a window handle to API and API render video on it.
I tried to render frames using SDL and it is OK. But when I destroy SDL_Window using SDL_DestroyWindow(), native window that other software pass its handle, is also destroyed.
Then I commented SDL_DestroyWindow part, but this time reusing same native window handle is a problem. When other software pass API the same native window handle and I create an SDL_Window using SDL_CreateWindowFrom(), other software can not get native window click events. 
Is there a way converting SDL_Window again to a native window? or do you have any solution suggestion for my problem?

Comment: What's your target OS and SDL version? SDL doesn't destroy system windows passed through SDL_CreateWindowFrom.

Comment: Operating System is Windows. SDL version is 2.0.4

Comment: What makes you think it destroys window? Checking the [code](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/e12c38730512/src/video/windows/SDL_windowswindow.c#l659) confirms SDL only destroys windows it itself created. Can you set breakpoint on `DestroyWindow` windows function and check where/if it is called from?

Comment: As you said source code seems ok. Now I write a basic .net code which passes a panel handle to API. When I destroy handle after first video rendering, video can not be rendered in second time. But when I debug code, I can verify that SDL can create SDL_Window, SDL_Texture and SDL_Renderer. Everthing seems ok but no rendering. If I do not destroy handle video is rendered but I can not get panel click events.

Comment: If I call SDL_DestroyWindow c# panel disappears

Comment: Ok while SDL never destroys window it actually [hides it](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/02509665751f/src/video/SDL_video.c#l2695). You can show it again with e.g. `ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW)` on windows.

Comment: @keltar that sounds like an answer

Comment: Thank you @keltar, it works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Keltar said, ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW) solves the problem. Since SDL hides the window when SDL_DestroyWindow() called, window should be shown by calling ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW)